# Java HashMap duplicate elements

Tags: java, dictionary

I want to add duplicate elements on hashmap

so:

```
put("name1", 1);
put("name1", 3);
put("name1", 3);
put("name2", 1);
put("name2", 3);
```

how i can do that?

Comment: what is the benefit of doing this? what are you trying to accomplish, maybe there is a better way of doing this if you give some more deatils

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a `Map<String, List<Integer>>` i.e. you map a string to a list of integers.

So, in this case, `name1` would map to a list of [1,3,3].

Obviously you'd have to write your own put method, in which you add the int to the list. Example:

```
put(String s, int i){
    List<Integer> list = map.get(s);
    if(list == null){
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        map.put(s, list);
    }
    list.add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The [ListMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) interface from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) may meet your requirements.  It allows duplicate keys *and* duplicate key/value pairs.

```
ListMultimap<String, Integer> m =
    ArrayListMultimap.create();
m.put("name1", 1);
m.put("name1", 3);
m.put("name1", 3);
m.put("name2", 1);
m.put("name2", 3);
System.out.println(m.get("name1")); // => [1, 3, 3]
System.out.println(m.get("name2")); // => [1, 3]
```

Also do you really need to preserve duplicate key/value pairs?  If not then a `HashMultimap` may be sufficient (and more efficient.)  If you insert the same entries into a `HashMultimap` you get:

```
System.out.println(m.get("name1")); // => [1, 3]
System.out.println(m.get("name2")); // => [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 5):

Your idea violates the contract of the [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface:

`An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.`

It'd understandably be confusing to the map when you ask:

```
map.get("name1")
```

It wouldn't know which value to get.

I'd use [dogbane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838400/java-hashmap-duplicate-elements/4838432#4838432)'s solution of mapping each key to a list of Integers.  In your example, you have possible duplicate values. If you don't want duplicate values (i.e. for "name1" there'd be only one 3 in the resulting list), you could instead make it a Map of Strings to [Sets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of Integers.

Answer (score 3):

You should use Google Collection's [Multimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) data structure.

> A collection similar to a Map, but
>   which may associate multiple values
>   with a single key. If you call put(K,
>   V) twice, with the same key but
>   different values, the multimap
>   contains mappings from the key to both
>   values.

This is exactly what you are trying to achieve. No need to re-invent the wheel by writing your custom Map operations in my opinion. Also you may find this [tutorial](http://www.factorypattern.com/multimap-in-google-collections-library/) on MultiMap useful.

Comment: More specifically I think it would need to be a `ListMultimap`.  A `SetMultimap` would not allow duplicate key/value pairs but there is one in the example input.  That article is a bit out of date.  Google Collections has since been merged into [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Comment: Right. Or you can use HashMultimap

Comment: `HashMultimap` does allow duplicate keys but not duplicate key/value pairs.  If you insert the example entries into a `HashMultimap` you end up with only one `name1=3` entry.

Comment: Right. Okay I went back and closely looked at the OP's data .. he/she does have a duplicate key/value pair ... at first I thought he/she was just needing duplicate keys. Thanks for pointing it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't , you can however create your own implementation of map which allows duplicates inside.

Comment: If it allows duplicates, it's not a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiValueMap is a more suitable choice.It can put one key to multiple values.

```
public Object put(Object key, Object value) {
    boolean result = false;
    Collection coll = getCollection(key);
    if (coll == null) {
        coll = createCollection(1);
        result = coll.add(value);
        if (coll.size() > 0) {
            // only add if non-zero size to maintain class state
            getMap().put(key, coll);
            result = false;
        }
    } else {
        result = coll.add(value);
    }
    return (result ? value : null);
}
```