# Java Development: Nested Array Equivalent to This XML

Tags: java, arrays, maps, key-value

I want to create multiple key/value arrays in Java that will sit in a master array.
I then want to be able to loop through the master array and grab the key/value of each array.

I want the array to be in a similar style to this XML:

```
<snippets>
  <snippet1>
    <name>Name</name>
    <desc>Desc</desc>
  </snippet1>
  <snippet2>
    <name>Name</name>
    <desc>Desc</desc>
  </snippet2>
</snippets>
```

or is there a way I can do this without using arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Collection's [Multimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) data structure. More specifically to get duplicate key/value pairs you can use [ListMultiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html).

Also take a look at this similar question.

- [Java HashMap duplicate elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838400/java-hashmap-duplicate-elements/4838492#4838492)

If you do not need duplicate key/value pairs, then just use standard java [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) implementation of the [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a good case for using classes :)
This should get you started (and is pretty unsophisticated):

```
class Snippets {
   private List<Snippet> snippets;
   List<Snippet> getSnippets() { ... };
   ...
}
class Snippet {
   private String name;
   private String desc;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY want to use arrays, here's an example:

```
String[][] snippets = new String[][] {
  new String[] { "Name" , "Desc" },
  new String[] { "Name2" , "Desc2" },
};

for(String[] pair: snippets) {
  String key = pair[0];
  String val = pair[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use (Hash)Maps and (Array)Lists.

You can store everything in a Object like this:

```
List<Map<String,String>> yourList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
map1.put("key1", "value1");
map1.put("key2", "value2");
yourList.add(map1);
```

This is how you loop through it:

```
for (Map<String,String> map: yourList) 
  for (Entry<String, String> entry: map.entrySet())
    System.out.println(entry.getKey()+": "+entry.getValue());
```

Comment: HashMap will not allow duplicate key value pairs as the OP asked for.

Comment: I thought "Name" and "Desc" should be placeholders. You'r right, I can't exactly rebuild his XML with Maps...

Comment: I am not exactly sure myself but just going by the data given in the question. I have added the assumption in my answer.

Comment: name and desc are meant to be keys, like <name>ExampleName</name>. Sorry for not making it clear enough :(

Comment: Sounds like you just need a simple HashMap. No need to create a list of Maps.

Comment: "I want to create multiple key/value arrays in Java" sounds for me like he want's to have more than one HashMap