# Java hashmap problem

Tags: java, hashmap

I would like to ask

in Hashmap

how can I count all the numbers if the element ID is same?

Could anyone give some idea for me?

Or just give some useful reference links for me to study

thanks

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class hash {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
        hashMap.put("ABS", new Double(3434.34));
        hashMap.put("ABD", new Double(123.22));
        hashMap.put("ABD", new Double(123.22));
        hashMap.put("ABD", new Double(123.22));
        hashMap.put("ABD", new Double(123.22));

        Set set = hashMap.entrySet();

        Iterator i = set.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
            System.out.println(me.getKey() + " : " + me.getValue());
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java HashMap duplicate elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838400/java-hashmap-duplicate-elements)

Answer (score 5):

You can't. You need a data structure that supports counting keys. Map implementations don't.

### Guava

One thing you can use is [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

**Sample Code:**

```
final Multimap<String, Double> map =
    Multimaps.newListMultimap(
        Maps.<String, Collection<Double>>newTreeMap(),
        new Supplier<List<Double>>(){

            @Override
            public List<Double> get() {
                return Lists.newArrayList();
            }});
map.put("ABS", Double.valueOf(3434.34));
map.put("ABD", Double.valueOf(123.22));
map.put("ABD", Double.valueOf(123.22));
map.put("ABD", Double.valueOf(123.22));
map.put("ABD", Double.valueOf(123.22));
for (final Multiset.Entry<String> key : map.keys().entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(
        "Key: "
        +key.getElement()
        +", count: "
        +key.getCount()
        +", values: "
        +map.get(key.getElement())
    );
}
```

**Output:**

> Key: ABD, count: 4, values: [123.22, 123.22, 123.22, 123.22]
>   Key: ABS, count: 1, values: [3434.34]

The MultiMap in Apache Commons / Collections will also do the trick.

---

### Plain Java

If you are not allowed to use an external library, you can still implement this functionality with a `Map<String, List<Double>>`. Create a method like this

**Helper Method**

```
public static <K, V> void assignValue(
    final Map<K, Collection<V>> map, final K key, final V value) {

    Collection<V> values = map.get(key);
    if(values==null){
        values=new ArrayList<V>();
        map.put(key, values);
    }
    values.add(value);
}
```

**Usage**

And use it like this:

```
final Map<String, Collection<Double>> map =
    new HashMap<String, Collection<Double>>();
assignValue(map, "ABS", Double.valueOf(3434.34));
assignValue(map, "ABD", Double.valueOf(123.22));
assignValue(map, "ABD", Double.valueOf(123.22));
assignValue(map, "ABD", Double.valueOf(123.22));
assignValue(map, "ABD", Double.valueOf(123.22));

for(final Entry<String, Collection<Double>> entry : map.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(new StringBuilder()
        .append("Key: ")
        .append(entry.getKey())
        .append(", count: ")
        .append(entry.getValue().size())
        .append(", values: ")
        .append(entry.getValue())
        .toString());
}
```

**Output**

> Key: ABD, count: 4, values: [123.22, 123.22, 123.22, 123.22]
>   Key: ABS, count: 1, values: [3434.34]

Answer (score 1):

HashMap is-a **Map** which cannot contain duplicate keys. If duplicate keys are allowed, which value will you expect to return when calling `map.get(duplicateKey)`?

Answer (score 1):

Have a read through [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), particularly the 'put' method which says:

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for this key, the old value is replaced.

The way you've structured your code means that the HashMap will only ever contain two key/value pairs.

```
public class hash {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
    hashMap.put("ABS", new Double(3434.34)); // "ABS" key created. 1 object in map.
    hashMap.put("ABD", new Double(123.22)); // "ABD" key created. 2 objects in map.
    hashMap.put("ABD", new Double(123.22)); // "ABD" reference will point to new value.
    hashMap.put("ABD", new Double(123.22)); // .. and again
    hashMap.put("ABD", new Double(123.22)); // .. and again
```

So while you've written five put lines, only two objects will ever be placed in the HashMap.

You can use

```
hashMap.size()
```

to return an int value of how many key/value pairs are in 'hashMap'.

Answer (score 0):

so you need to have Double+Count as value then and use it instead of Double, as a exercise make it extend java.lang.Number :)

```
Class DoubleCount{
  final double value;
  private int count;
  DoubleCount(double value){
    this.value = value;
  }
  public int getCount(){
    return count;
  } 

  public double getValue(){
   return value;
  }

  public int incCount(){
    return ++count;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`size = hashMap.size();`
then use for loop to iterate

Comment: that's not correct, he's re-assigning the same key and wants to count the reassignments