# duplicate entry in map in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, data-structures

I'm reading a json object and to setting them as key value pair into a HashMap, things were fine till now. Now I come across a problem that I have a particular key which is duplicated in the json object but with different values.

eg:

"id": 31231

"id": 33445

I would require both these values now. Can anyone recommend me the best data structure to store these data.

Comment: `Map<String,Set<Integer>>` ?

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838400/java-hashmap-duplicate-elements/4838434#4838434

Comment: Having the same key twice in a single JSON object is not valid JSON!

Comment: As @JoachimSauer says, **this is not valid JSON**. Any sane JSON parser will either select one random value for the key, or throw an error. I am curious as to what JSON library you are using... (edit: so that I never use it)

Comment: @fge,  They were as keys in a different objects in the same json parent objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) or make your own `Map<String,List<Value>`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make the `Map` value a `List` and add both values to it.  It's called a multi-map.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiMap  The multiMap available in **Commons Collections 3.2.1 API**

```
       MultiMap multiMap = new MultiValueMap();
       multiMap.put("key", 12334);
       multiMap.put("key", 31231);
       multiMap.put("key", 12312);
       multiMap.put("key", 12312);
       System.out.println(multiMap);
```

{key=[12334, 31231, 12312, 12312]}

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `Map<String,Set<Integer>>`, if you don't want the duplicate values against the same json object. Otherwise you can define the set like this: `Map<String,List<Integer>>`. where json object is the key and the value is set/list of integer values against the json object. 
This is how your code logic should be

Before inserting an entry in the hashmap, check whether the key already exists

- a. If key does not exist then create a new set/list, add the value to the
  se/list and insert it  against the key
- b. If key exists, fetch the set/list against the key and add an element in
  the set

Hope you should be able to code that.

Comment: This does not allow two values to be equal.

Comment: I assumed it to be sensible that we should not have same object and with same value. But let me update it in the resolution in case user really wants to store the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

[Guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) also contains [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) interface along with variety of implementations.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you keep a JSON Array instead of a single value for the key id. This is how your JSON will look after implementing the above suggestion:

```
{"ids": [{"id": "a"}, {"id": "b"}], "x": "c", "y": "d", ...  }
```

While reading just take the value (JSON Array) for the ids key and iterate through it and get id from the JSON objects inside the JSON Array.

I thinks it should work fine for your problem.